# htaccess ignore subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, wamp, subdirectory

I have problem with my `.htaccess` file (or wamp setup).

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^directory/?$ directory.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^directory/subdirectory/?$ subdirectory.php [L,NC]
```

When I go to my_web/directory/ - everything is OK, but when I go to my_web/directory/subdirectory/ then show directory.php (url in browser is directory/subdirectory/).

When I write url without rule (example `/test/`) and I have `test.php` then automatically show `test.php`. Why?

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect you have a caching issue here. Try disabling your browser cache or do a "deep reload".

Comment: @arkascha: This not work for me.

Comment: Maybe you have other rewriting rules defined at another place. Best is to do two things: 1. stop using dynamic configuration files, such rewriting rules better belong into the http servers host configuration anyway and 2. enable rewrite logging (see the documentation), that feature allows to understand what exactly is going on inside your rewriting engine on a step by step level.

Comment: @arkascha: I try everything, but no results...

Comment: OK, but I guess you know that we cannot really help with a &amp;quot;i tried everything, but no results&amp;quot;... What have you tried? Exactly?